# Java SSL Server disable weak elliptic curves

Tags: java, security, ssl, server

So this is the code of my Java ssl Server. `ctx` is an `SSLContext` initialised with the server keystore.

```
public SSLEngine createSSLEngine() {

        SSLEngine sslEngine = ctx.createSSLEngine();

        String[] ciphersuites = new String[]{
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
                "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
        };

        sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(ciphersuites);

        sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);

        return sslEngine;
    }
```

I tested it with cipherscan (https://github.com/jvehent/cipherscan), the ciphersuites look fine, but the server supports all possible elliptic curves (sect163k1, sect163r1, sect163r2, sect193r1, sect193r2, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect239k1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, secp192k1, prime192v1, secp224k1, secp224r1, secp256k1, prime256v1, secp384r1, secp521r1).

Is there a way to disable all curves, except the strong ones like secp384r1?

Answer (score 9):

As of Java8 u121 it is possible to configure which elliptic curve are to be used.

Use a parameter at VM startup of your programm i.e.:

```
-Djdk.tls.namedGroups="secp521r1, secp256r1, secp256k1"
```

Or if you want a JDK/JRE wide policy alter the java.security file and add the property. i.e.:

```
jdk.tls.namedGroups=secp521r1, secp256r1, secp256k1
```

As reference see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u121-relnotes-3315208.html paragraph "Improve the default strength of EC in JDK"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Here are my findings which only partially solve the issue:

1. TLS with elliptical curves are based on RFC 3546 (TLS extensions) and RFC 4492 (TLS extension for elliptical curves)
2. Java implements these extensions in `com.sun.security.ssl.HelloExtension` (which lists all extensions) and `com.sun.security.ssl.SupportedEllipticCurves` (which is the elliptic curve extension providing a list of allowed curves)
3. Sadly, these classes are included in the JVM and it seems there is no way of just modifying the list with a parameter. :(
4. I read a bugfix report which shall be included in Java 9.1, which may include a configuration feature. So 2018, I guess?

Ignoring the licenses of OpenJDK (GPLv2+Classpath exception) and Oracle JDK (here: Java Environment Binary Licence) for a moment, here is a way to technically fix the issue:

1. take the code from the OpenJDK, e.g. the class `com.sun.security.ssl.SupportedEllipticCurves`
2. modify it accordingly (the list of curve IDs can be found in `com.sun.ec.CurveDB.java`)
3. compile a jar
4. use `Xbootclasspath:prepend` to load your class with the modified list of curves and ignore the JVM one.

And than there is the license issue...

For example, jetty-alpn-agent is doing it. And it is put under GPLv2+exception as well. I am not a lawyer but I think you could create an open-source project, do your thing, put it under GPLv2+extension as well, then just use it.